# How can I generate 5 minutes interval data in SQL Server from a given start date to an end date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME
DECLARE @end   DATETIME

SET @start = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';
SET @end = '2015-03-05 00:00:00';
```

OUTPUT should be:

```
2015-01-01 00:05:00
2015-01-01 00:10:00
2015-01-01 00:15:00
2015-01-01 00:20:00
2015-01-01 00:25:00
.
.
.
till the end date
```

Answer (score 1):

If open to a helper function.  I often use a parameter driven Table-Value Function.

As a TVF, it is easy to use within a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE @end   DATETIME = '2015-03-05 00:00:00';

Select * 
  From [dbo].[tvf-Date-Range](@start,@end,'mi',5)
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
2       2015-01-01 00:05:00.000
3       2015-01-01 00:10:00.000
4       2015-01-01 00:15:00.000
---
18143   2015-03-04 23:50:00.000
18144   2015-03-04 23:55:00.000
18145   2015-03-05 00:00:00.000
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Date-Range] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE is an easy solution:

```
with dates as (
      select @start as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(minute, 5, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < @end
     )
select *
from dates
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another one:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE @end DATETIME = '2015-03-05 00:00:00';
DECLARE @minuteInterval INT = 5;

DECLARE @count INT = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @start, @end) / @minuteInterval + 1;

WITH N1 AS (SELECT N = 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1), -- 2
     N2 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N), -- 4
     N3 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM N2 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N), -- 16
     N4 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM N3 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N), -- 256
     N5 AS (SELECT N = 1 FROM N4 CROSS JOIN N4 AS N),  -- 65536
     Numbers AS (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM N5)
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @minuteInterval * (Numbers.Number - 1), @start)
FROM Numbers
WHERE Numbers.Number <= @count;
```

Numbers CTE contains range from 1 to 65536. Then for each number we are adding Number * 5 minutes from @start date up to @end date.

Comment: Explain what this is ment to be?

Answer (score 0):

I would, personally, suggest a Tally. They are significantly faster than recursive Common Table Expressions, as they aren't recursive (something which RDBMS are not designed to excel at). Especially when you have lots of rows.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime2(0) = '20200401',
        @EndDate datetime2(0) = '20200501';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP ((DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@StartDate, @EndDate) / 5) +1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5) --up to 100,000 rows, add for cross joins for more rows
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, I*5, @StartDate) AS DateAndTime
FROM Tally;
```